# Windows Service - Is it possible to update some variables while the service is running?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, filesystemwatcher

I'm creating a FileSystemWatcher Windows Service, connected to a Windows Forms Application.
Through my Windows Forms Application I am sending the path which needs to be monitored by the FileSystemWatcher Service. My question is, without stopping the service and then sending another path that I want to monitor, is it possible to send the new path and and to start monitoring that file?

Here's quick insight of how my program works:

1. Send path to FileSystemWatcher Service;
2. Start service;
   //Let's say I now want to monitor another folder
3. Stop service;
4. Give new path;
5. Start service;

Answer (score 0):

There's a few solutions to inter-process communication but a great option is [named pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication).

There's a really nice [step by step example](https://erikengberg.com/named-pipes-in-net-6-with-tray-icon-and-service/) which uses a Windows Service to send data to a system tray icon. In this example, the Window Service is also the named pipe server.

In your case, your windows service will be a client, listening to data from your Windows Forms application.